# Missing Rails gem error, but its installed!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rvm

So I'm new to rails and am actually following a video tutorial from Lynda.com in order to learn it.  I didn't follow the steps to install on the video because I heard of RVM and its been great so far with getting everything setup.  But I'm still early on in the video and can't get passed something really simple... so I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Heres some background:

- I have RVM installed and created
  1.8.7@rails2.3.8.  I was able to install both ruby and rails, and
  everything here is fine.  I even
  setup a global gemset for mysql and
  passenger.
- I'm using passenger instead of
  WEBrick (which the tutorial uses) and
  I was even able to get the apache
  module loaded and everything is
  working fine when I create a rails
  app.  I can go to simple-cms.local and I
  see the intro page fine.

So here is the issue.  While following the video, I got to the point where I `script/generate controller say` and it created the controller fine, no errors.  I then proceeded to define an action "hello" in the controller, and the corresponding view "hello.rhtml" in the app/view/say folder.

Now, when I try to visit simple-cms.local, it still works, but when I try to visit simple-cms.local/say/hello.rhtml, I get an error!

> Ruby on Rails application could not be
>   started
>
> The application has exited during
>   startup (i.e. during the evaluation of
>   config/environment.rb). The error
>   message can be found below. To solve
>   this problem, please follow any
>   instructions in the error message.
>
> Error message: Missing the Rails 2.3.8
>   gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.8
>   rails`, update your RAILS_GEM_VERSION
>   setting in config/environment.rb for
>   the Rails version you do have
>   installed, or comment out
>   RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest
>   version installed.

So what do I do here?  I mean rails 2.3.8 is installed, so why is it telling me to install it again?

---

**UPDATE:**

I ran `gem environment` from within the app directory and got this

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-darwin10.4.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails2
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p302/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails2/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails2
     - /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Then ran `script/console`, which worked and then ran `Gems.path`, which returned

```
["/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@rails2", "/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302@global"]
```

Looks fine to me, what about you guys?

---

**UPDATE 2:**

Ok, so nothing has worked for me!  I haven't yet tried Passenger Standalone, but I need to use apache and I read that standalone uses nginx.  What I tried so far is started from scratch, `rvm implode` and then installed rvm again, ruby 1.8.7, passenger, mysql, rails 2.3.8, and thats it.  I still can't get passed the default page when visiting my app!  I also then tried following the guides Chris Johnsen linked to in the comments to no avail.

All ideas are welcome...

Comment: have you other rails version in your gem list ?

Comment: It looks like Passenger is not properly configured to use your RVM gemset. Searching for “passenger rvm” turned up these: [Using Passenger with rvm](http://urgetopunt.com/2009/09/27/passenger-with-rvm.html), [Using RVM rubies with Passenger](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/), [Advice on using Ruby, RVM, Passenger, Rails, Bundler, … in development](http://jeremy.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/ruby-rvm-passenger-rails-bundler-in-development/), and [The Path to Better RVM & Passenger Integration](http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration).

Comment: Yup, I have also installed 1.9.2@rails3, but rvm is supposed to keep these separate right? And passenger was configured for 1.8.7, I saw that there are ways to install passenger standalone if i want to work with it on 1.9.2 also, but for right now I just want to get started with 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was installing passenger into the global gemset, which shouldn't be a problem, but it was.

I uninstalled passenger from the global gemset, and installed it into the project gemset that I'm using.  This solved the missing rails gem error, and now I'm getting a 500 error when trying to visit simple-cms.local/say/hello.  I'll create a new question for that and mark this one solved!

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I was getting the 500 error because sqlite3-ruby was not installed.  "gem install sqlite3-ruby"... fixed now and everything is working :-), i can finally start messing around with ruby!

Answer (score 0):

Try Phusion Passenger Standalone. Each instance will use the currently loaded RVM and gemset.