# Rails 3.0, RVM: still getting "Could not find ... in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm, passenger

I have following (and have shortened the full path to "/.../"):

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.21
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2012-02-14 patchlevel 318) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails-3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails-3.0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails-3.0
     - /.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

As you can see I have @global and @rails-3.0 gemsets. Passenger 3.0.11 is installed in the @global gemset, and I have a .rmvrc file in my application root:

```
rvm ruby-1.9.2-p318@rails-3.0
```

However, after running `$ bundle install` and restarting the app via `$ touch tmp/restart.txt` I keep getting the Passenger error screen with the following:

```
Error message: Could not find aaronh-chronic-0.3.9 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

This gem is installed in the @rails-3.0 gemset

- [Gemfile here.](https://gist.github.com/2343439)
- [`$ gem list` here](https://gist.github.com/2320974)

If I install the aaronh-chronic gem in the @global gemset, then it just complains about the next one in line. It's like it is only checking the @global gemset instead of first looking in my @rails-3.0 gemset. How can I get it to use both gemsets? [(Full backtrace here.)](https://gist.github.com/2321025)

**UPDATE:** Here is my Passenger Apache configuration:

```
# In /etc/apache2/mods_available/passenger.load
LoadModule passenger_module /.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so

# In /etc/apache2/mods_available/passenger.conf
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
  PassengerRoot /.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global/gems/passenger-3.0.11
  PassengerRuby /.../.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p318@global/ruby
</IfModule>
```

Comment: please add your passenger configuration in apache

Comment: Please add your Gemfile contents

Comment: Hello, I added a link to my Gemfile contents and then my Passenger Apache config at the bottom. Thank you.

Comment: PS. I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136894/missing-rails-gem-error-but-its-installed with the accepted answer saying it worked when Passenger was installed in application's gemset instead of the global gemset. I tried this and it worked, but this would require changing the apache config every time a new gemset is used and seems to defeat the purpose of gemsets. There has to be a way to use Passenger in the global gemset...

Answer (score 0):

Try bundle update and gem update --system.